# WannaCry - block callback IP/domain?

Tags: malware, ransomware, wannacry

While new variants of [Wannacry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack) has sprung up, the old variant is still lurking around corners and I am not sure whether the following callback IPs and domains should be blocked as per typical ransomware playbooks/runbooks, since they now double as a [kill switch to a sinkhole](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2017/05/15/wannacry-new-kill-switch-new-sinkhole/):

### Domains:

- iuqerfsodp9ifjaposdfjhgosurijfaewrwergwea.com
- ifferfsodp9ifjaposdfjhgosurijfaewrwergwea.com
- iuqerfsodp9ifjaposdfjhgosurijfaewrwergweb.com
- iuqssfsodp9ifjaposdfjhgosurijfaewrwergwea.com
- ayylmaotjhsstasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.com

### IPs

- 144.217.254.3
- 144.217.74.156
- 184.168.221.43
- 217.182.141.137
- 217.182.172.139
- 52.57.88.48
- 54.153.0.145
- 79.137.66.14

Should the above be blocked? Or allowed to communicate to act as kill switch?

(This question is different from [How is the “WannaCry” Malware spreading and how should users defend themselves from it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159331/how-is-the-wannacry-malware-spreading-and-how-should-users-defend-themselves-f) as the typical response is to block all [C&C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_control_(malware)) domains/IPs, but in this case, I'm not certain since the flawed C&C acted as a kill switch)

[source](https://www.lastline.com/blog/wannacry-ransomware/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the "WannaCry" Malware spreading and how should users defend themselves from it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159331/how-is-the-wannacry-malware-spreading-and-how-should-users-defend-themselves-f)

Comment: that link above doesn't answer my question. mine is juxtaposing two options

Answer (score 2):

To act as a kill switch they must connect.

So the safest way to do it is probably to respond for them: when one of there domain/IP is requested, fake the answer.